# Modeling objects (OOP) in dependent type theory

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, coq, dependent-type

I am interested in modeling objects, from object oriented programming, in dependent type theory. As a possible application, I would like to have a model where I can describe different features of imperative programming languages.

I could only find one Paper on modeling objects in dependent type theory, which is:
[Object-oriented programming in dependent type theory by A. Setzer (2006)](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csetzer/articles/objectOrientedProgrammingInDepTypeTheoryTfp2006PostProceedings.pdf)

Are there further references on the topic that I missed and perhaps are there more recent ones?

Is there perhaps an implementation (i.e. proof) available for a theorem prover, like Coq or Agda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some early(?) work done in this area was by Bart Jacobs (Nijmegen) and Marieke Huisman. Their work is based on the PVS tool and relied on a coalgebraic encoding of classes (if I remember correctly). Look at Marieke's [publication page](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~marieke/papers.html) for papers in the year 2000 and her PhD thesis in 2001. Also look at the papers by Bart Jacobs cited in the A Setzer paper you mention.

Back in those days, they had something called the LOOP tool, but it seems to have vanished from the internets.

There is a workshop series known as [FTfJP](http://www.cs.ru.nl/ftfjp/) (Formal Techniques for Java-like Programs) that addresses the formal verification of OO programs. Undoubtedly some of the work uses dependent type theory/higher-order logic. The workshop series has been running for some 14 years.

Answer (score 3):

There is a substantially expanded follow paper Andreas Abel, Stephan Adelsberger, Anton Setzer: [Interactive Programming in Agda - 
Objects and Graphical User Interfaces](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csetzer/articles/ooAgda.pdf). It contains an [Agda library](https://github.com/agda/ooAgda) for writing object-based programs, inluding GUIs. There are some follow up papers with Stephan Adelsberger on writing verified GUIs in the medical domain in Agda based on object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

I am not well-versed enough in the subject to give a decent overview, but I would advise to scavenge the bibliography of the late 2010 PhD thesis of Seokhyun Han, [*Verification of Java Programs in Type Theory with Dependent Record Types and Coercive Subtyping*](https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~seokhyun/).

Some [recent work on separation logic](https://www.itu.dk/people/jobr/itp2011.pdf) also seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you looking at *dependent* type theory to represent OOP? Can't we
model OOP in a satisfying way with non-dependent calculi? I have an
informal model of what OOP looks like, say, when translated to System
F (or Fω if you want to support generics), and I don't see where the
type-value dependency would come into play.

Dependent types can be used, for example, to give a lower-level
meaning to algebraic data types. You could probably do such
a low-level encoding of OO features, but I'm not sure that's better
than adding algebraic datatypes to your modeling language.

Maybe you want to give a finer static semantics to OOP constructs that
are currently untyped, such as `instance_of` followed by
a `cast`. I can see dependent type hackery being useful to statically
reason about such programs; but I'm not sure it would "model" those
operations that concentrate on the dynamic angle, it's something more.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This isn't a discussion forum.